# Exception handling in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, exception

I was going through the Blog tutorial on the cakePHP website and came across this error handling code :

```
$post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
```

So why have they used (__('Invalid post') as the argument when we simply can use

```
if (!$post) {
    throw new NotFoundException('Invalid post');
}
```

Comment: are you asking why did they chose that particular error message, or why are they using the `__()` function?

Comment: Look __(), __d(), __n(), __dn() up, api.cakephp.org, this is for translations.

Comment: i meant __() function. I do not understand the reason behind down voting this question though.

Comment: The most likely reason for the down votes is you did not put enough effort into finding the answer before posting here. All you had to do was search for `__` on api.cakephp.org.

Comment: That was because I did not think that was even a function _() like this. I will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__() is a function used for internationalization meaning it first try to show translated text, if not found it shows the text provided. If you're not developing a multi language website just ignore it! 
for more information visit book.cakephp.org

Comment: Even if you're not developing a multi language website, in most cases it's best practice to localise messages. It allows you to come up with friendlier messages without having to alter your code and manage all those messages from a single location (a single `.po` file. Also, it allows you to re-use your code in projects that *are* multi-language